# Using a private class in place of a field - performance/memory penalty?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm reviewing someone's code and came across this private class:

```
class CustomType : Dictionary<int, SomeOtherCustomType>
{
    // This is empty; nothing omitted here
}
```

CustomType is then used all over the parent class. This is neat of course, since CustomType is shorter than

```
Dictionary<int, SomeOtherCustomType>
```

My question is, what are the performance/memory implications of having an inner class just for a shortcut? In a performance sensitive application, does this contribute (even slightly) to higher memory and/or CPU usage?

Comment: It will affect any code changes that may need to make use of the other constructors of `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, you would need to add them to the base class.

Comment: If you want to know what the penalty is in your *performance sensitive application* then run the code through your *performance test suite* twice, once with the type as declared, and once with it merely an alias as Dr. Jones suggests. You will then know precisely what the difference is. And if you don't have a performance test suite then **you have bigger problems to solve**, namely, you have no idea what the performance of your "performance sensitive application" really is.

Comment: FWIW Jefferey Richter specifically mentions this pattern in CLR via C# and recommends against it and for using `using` on the grounds that methods that use a parameter of type `CustomType` will not be able to be passed a `Dictionary<int, SomeOtherCustomType>`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The short and the long of it is, no. The class `CustomType` is by definition a `Dictionary<int, SomeOtherCustomType>` and so it will be allocated as such.

This is particularly true because there literally is no implementation for the class.

Comment: Well, technically, it's one more type that has to be loaded which probably has a tiny constant overhead. (Seeing as the OP is being rather obsessive here.)

Comment: @millimoose, I could see that and good addition, but as you stated it would be extremely tiny because it would be a one-time constant.

Comment: If it will be memory overhead, it won't be one-time. Loading your memory with garbage creates everytime overhead, known as _cache miss penalty_. I understand that cache hit rate is not a concern among the programmers because CPU speed rather than memory access is a bottleneck in the modern, multicore computers. Right?

Comment: @Val, .NET only loads the type one time. So it's not loading the memory with any garbage. Further, because there is no implementation **and** it's based the `Dictionary` -allocation will occur just like it would if you were strictly build a `Dictionary`.

Comment: Claiming that something is loaded (into memory) does not load the memory is a bit couterlogical.

Comment: @Val, I'm sorry, but I don't understand your response. Please clarify.

Comment: And let's face it, it's only a matter of time till some functionality is added to `CustomType` - and that's good!

Answer (score 50):

Unless there's another reason for defining a custom type I'd suggest changing it to a using statement.

```
using CustomType = Dictionary<int, SomeOtherCustomType>;
```

It just defines an alias for the dictionary and can be quite useful if you're consuming some complicated parameterised classes.

This eliminates the need of declaring a new type, because as the code stands at the moment the following would fail.

```
CustomType dictionary = new Dictionary<int, SomeOtherCustomType>(); //custom type is a different class and can't be instantiated with a dictionary
```

However, it would work if you use an alias instead.

Comment: I didn't even realise you could use `using` aliases for that. (Having them point to generic instantiations of types instead of the "raw" types.)

Comment: Though, this would mean you'd need that alias in every file that uses the CustomType.

Comment: @zimdanen - It is a private class anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith:  Good call; missed that.

Comment: This a very good advice, but in the same time does not answer the question at all !

Comment: @C4stor if "The answer can be 'don’t do that'" ([How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)), I believe that "You're focusing on the wrong aspect" is also acceptable.

Comment: Even if CustomType was being used in other files, the alias *should* be duplicated in each file rather than made a subtype, because it *is* an alias. You could consider this a deficiency in the language, but should never work around it by expressing code in a way that contradicts reality: When you say CustomType inherits Dictionary<a, b>, you're saying that a Dictionary<a, b> *is not* a CustomType, which isn't true and will become a problem as soon as you decide you want to accept a dictionary from outside the class and assign it to your CustomType variable.

Comment: Depending on the use case, this may not be a good suggestion. If it's to save typing, I agree with an alias. If it's to give the dictionary a more intention-revealing name in the domain, I'm less in favor. If a refactoring were to promote this to a public class, a usage statement is problematic across multiple classes. And, as the concept grows, a separate class could also extend the dictionary. I don't this the OP contains enough context to decide.